# Pointer and vectors in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm starting with C++ and I have a doubts:

I'm making a function which will return a vector of objects of a class `MyClass`.

```
vector<MyClass>* myMethod()
```

The first question is, it's correct to return a pointer?

The second question is: if I'm going to return a pointer, should I also insert pointer of MyClass object into the vector?

```
MyClass* object;
myVector.push_back(*object);
```

Comment: `I'm making a function which will return a vector of objects of a class MyClass` No, you're not. You're returning a pointer.

Comment: `it's correct to return a pointer?` That depends on many, many things.

Comment: Your code sample (a) uses an invalid pointer and invalid dereference of said invalid pointer; (b) makes no sense because you're not inserting a pointer into the vector at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with method that returns pointer to vector like this: `vector<MyClass>* myMethod()`. But you should ask yourself some questions, like:

1. Does it have to be pointer to vector? Can't it be just `vector<MyClass>` ?
2. Should this method also allocate memory for this vector?
3. Should caller of this method `delete` / `free` this memory ?

And to your second question: I would make vector of pointers to objects of `MyClass` (`vector<MyClass*>`) only if it is really necessary. It will cause you some troubles with memory management, so let's choose an easier way.

Ok, let's talk about this question: **Should this method also allocate memory for this vector?**
If the purpose of this method is to **create** a vector, then **yes**, the method should also allocate memory for it:

```
vector<MyClass>* myMethod()
{
    vector<MyClass>* v = new vector<MyClass>;
    // initialize, fill or do whatever with this vector
    return v;
}
```

caller should clean up then:

```
    vector<MyClass>* v = myMethod();
    // do some stuff
    delete v; // clean up
```

If the purpose is just to retrieve the pointer to some specific vector that can not be obtained by caller, it could look like this:

```
vector<MyClass> _x; // caller can not access _x but myMethod can

vector<MyClass>* myMethod()
{
    return &_x;
}
```

caller shouldn't delete this vector in this case:

```
    vector<MyClass>* v = myMethod();
    // do some stuff, don't delete v
```

Comment: Question 2: does the method automatically allocate the memory for me if I return a pointer to a vector? If I'm not going to return a pointer when the vector will be removed from the memory? Thanks!

Comment: Last question ;) It's if I don't return a pointer also if I allocate the memory? (`vector<MyClass>* v = new vector<MyClass>`)

Comment: If you return vector (`vector<int> myMethod()`) and caller calls `vector<int> v; v = myMethod();`, then copy of vector that you have returned from your method is created and stored into `v`.

Answer (score 10):

A vector can be a vector of objects or a vector of pointers. This is completely independent of whether you have a vector or a pointer to the vector.

If you are starting out with C++ try to avoid pointers altogether. Just return a vector of objects. Remember that the vector *contains* its contents. When you put an object into a vector it will be *copied* in.

Comment: Thanks, mow my question is: when you suggest me to use pointers to vector?

Answer (score 5):

In C++11, you can simply return `std::vector<T>`, and it will be fast. No temporary goes useless, as `std::vector` supports move-semantic, which means the resources allocated for temporary will be stolen by the move-semantic functions.

And if your type `T` manages resources, then you should  implement move-semantic as well, along with usual copy-semantic.

Comment: And even without C++11 returning `std::vector<T>` would often be fine. RVO exists long before 2011.

Comment: @KennyTM: RVO isn't guaranteed in all cases.

Comment: @Nawaz: automatic moves from local variables only occur if the criteria for copy elision are met in the first place.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I didn't understand your comment and why you're saying it in the first place?

Comment: @Nawaz: because if copy elision cannot happen, automatic moves cannot happen either.

Comment: @Nawaz Can I modify the vector if I don't return a pointer to it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may return a pointer to a vector and meaning of this is that you want to be able to modify this vector. Just keep in mind that you must not return a pointer to local variable.

As for pushing pointers in the vector - it depends on what do you want to do, but you don't HAVE TO push poiners.